# SymGetSymFromAddr64 showing only DLL symbols, not from my code

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to print the stack using SymGetSymFromAddr64 and SymGetLineFromAddr64, on a _M_X64 machine.

The output I am getting is:

```
Call stack (MAIN thread):
#0  at (null):0
#1  at (null):0
#2  at (null):0
#3  at (null):0
#4 BaseThreadInitThunk at (null):0
#5 RtlUserThreadStart at (null):0
```

It seems that SymGetSymFromAddr64 is only reporting symbols from DLLs, not my code, and SymGetLineFromAddr64 is not working at all. When not working, both functions produce the error "Attempt to access invalid address". This is code compiled with gcc -g on mingw. Any ideas?

```
    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE thread  = GetCurrentThread();

    SymInitialize (process, NULL, true);

    SymSetOptions (SymGetOptions() | SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);

    DWORD image_file = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64;
    STACKFRAME64 sf = { .AddrPC     = { .Mode = AddrModeFlat, .Offset = thread_ctx.Rip },
                        .AddrStack  = { .Mode = AddrModeFlat, .Offset = thread_ctx.Rsp },
                        .AddrFrame  = { .Mode = AddrModeFlat, .Offset = thread_ctx.Rbp } };
    
    int frame=0; 
    while (StackWalk64 (image_file, process, thread, &sf, &thread_ctx, NULL, SymFunctionTableAccess64, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL) &&
           sf.AddrPC.Offset) {

        union symbol {
            IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64;
            char data[sizeof(IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64) + MAX_SYM_NAME];
        } symbol = { { .SizeOfStruct = sizeof (union symbol), .MaxNameLength = MAX_SYM_NAME } };

        DWORD64 displacement = 0;
        SymGetSymFromAddr64 (process, sf.AddrPC.Offset, &displacement, (PIMAGEHLP_SYMBOL64)&symbol);
        
        IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line = { .SizeOfStruct = sizeof (IMAGEHLP_LINE64) };
        DWORD displacement2 = 0;
        SymGetLineFromAddr64 (process, sf.AddrPC.Offset, &displacement2, &line);
        
        fprintf (stderr, "#%u %s at %s:%u\n", frame++, symbol.Name, line.FileName, (uint32_t)line.LineNumber);
    }

    CloseHandle (thread);
    SymCleanup (process);
```

Comment: Do you have symbol information (.pdb files) in a path where the DbgHelp API is looking for (see [`SymInitialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-syminitialize))?